# Where do i need to write custom methods except the CRUD operation methods in repository pattern with efcore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a add method in repository to add a new customer  and before adding data to db i need to generate the latest Id of the customer to add It in the database .Suppose that method is getlatestcustomerid and there are some extra custom logic too . Where should i write custom logics in asp.net mvc application ?

Comment: why do you not use auto generated ids? or Guids so it can be generated by the object itself?

Comment: This problem is is it not a greenfield project . I am converting an existing windows based application to web application . besides that there are many custom logics too .So I am not understanding where to put them